# ggplot2: Line plots "crazy"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on this quite a while now and have received help by this community, but one problem leads to the next one. For now, the plots is a bit "crazy"

[image]

There should be three lines (`Plot_df$sector` ETS, regulated, unregulated)

I've tried to create a loop in order to create plots for several countries.

My dataframe: `Plot_df`

Here an excerpt of the data:

```
      year country iso2      sector emissions
378   1990 Austria   AT         ETS         0
2836  1990 Austria   AT   Regulated  38264403
3100  1990 Austria   AT Unregulated  24027828
409   1991 Austria   AT         ETS         0
5100  1991 Austria   AT   Regulated  39318197
6100  1991 Austria   AT Unregulated  26581483
440   1992 Austria   AT         ETS         0
8100  1992 Austria   AT   Regulated  34823803
9100  1992 Austria   AT Unregulated  25607658
471   1993 Austria   AT         ETS         0
11100 1993 Austria   AT   Regulated  35193747
12100 1993 Austria   AT Unregulated  25593991
502   1994 Austria   AT         ETS         0
14100 1994 Austria   AT   Regulated  36260166
15100 1994 Austria   AT Unregulated  24930182
533   1995 Austria   AT         ETS         0
17100 1995 Austria   AT   Regulated  38441281
18100 1995 Austria   AT Unregulated  25764669
564   1996 Austria   AT         ETS         0
20100 1996 Austria   AT   Regulated  39489370
21100 1996 Austria   AT Unregulated  28184521
595   1997 Austria   AT         ETS         0
23100 1997 Austria   AT   Regulated  41822882
24100 1997 Austria   AT Unregulated  25630126
626   1998 Austria   AT         ETS         0
26100 1998 Austria   AT   Regulated  39063198
27100 1998 Austria   AT Unregulated  27991169
657   1999 Austria   AT         ETS         0
2910  1999 Austria   AT   Regulated  38127128
3010  1999 Austria   AT Unregulated  27493880
688   2000 Austria   AT         ETS         0
3210  2000 Austria   AT   Regulated  38294108
3310  2000 Austria   AT Unregulated  27967635
719   2001 Austria   AT         ETS         0
3510  2001 Austria   AT   Regulated  40723095
3610  2001 Austria   AT Unregulated  29667765
750   2002 Austria   AT         ETS         0
3810  2002 Austria   AT   Regulated  41130208
3910  2002 Austria   AT Unregulated  31016331
781   2003 Austria   AT         ETS         0
4110  2003 Austria   AT   Regulated  44805099
4210  2003 Austria   AT Unregulated  32959151
812   2004 Austria   AT         ETS         0
4410  2004 Austria   AT   Regulated  44921799
4510  2004 Austria   AT Unregulated  33130748
1     2005 Austria   AT         ETS  33373156
4710  2005 Austria   AT   Regulated  47032869
4810  2005 Austria   AT Unregulated  32333810
26    2006 Austria   AT         ETS  32384372
5010  2006 Austria   AT   Regulated  46050726
5110  2006 Austria   AT Unregulated  30637735
51    2007 Austria   AT         ETS  31751260
5310  2007 Austria   AT   Regulated  43754649
5410  2007 Austria   AT Unregulated  30277468
78    2008 Austria   AT         ETS  32078974
5610  2008 Austria   AT   Regulated  44826920
5710  2008 Austria   AT Unregulated  28979354
107   2009 Austria   AT         ETS  27359832
5910  2009 Austria   AT   Regulated  39430745
6010  2009 Austria   AT Unregulated  28052317
136   2010 Austria   AT         ETS  30919712
6210  2010 Austria   AT   Regulated  42836143
6310  2010 Austria   AT Unregulated  29546998
165   2011 Austria   AT         ETS  30599418
6510  2011 Austria   AT   Regulated  42148355
6610  2011 Austria   AT Unregulated  27967317
194   2012 Austria   AT         ETS  28387060
6810  2012 Austria   AT   Regulated  39494447
6910  2012 Austria   AT Unregulated  28166952
223   2013 Austria   AT         ETS  29804410
7110  2013 Austria   AT   Regulated  38573958
7210  2013 Austria   AT Unregulated  29427268
254   2014 Austria   AT         ETS  28055974
7410  2014 Austria   AT   Regulated  36311073
7510  2014 Austria   AT Unregulated  27942255
285   2015 Austria   AT         ETS  29492064
7710  2015 Austria   AT   Regulated  38003088
7810  2015 Austria   AT Unregulated  28700896
316   2016 Austria   AT         ETS  29000120
8010  2016 Austria   AT   Regulated  37651775
8110  2016 Austria   AT Unregulated  29750311
347   2017 Austria   AT         ETS  30555226
813   1990 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
8310  1990 Belgium   BE   Regulated  78614107
8410  1990 Belgium   BE Unregulated  41870292
379   1991 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
8610  1991 Belgium   BE   Regulated  79811521
8710  1991 Belgium   BE Unregulated  43733190
410   1992 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
8910  1992 Belgium   BE   Regulated  78283962
9010  1992 Belgium   BE Unregulated  44373851
441   1993 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
9210  1993 Belgium   BE   Regulated  76752290
9310  1993 Belgium   BE Unregulated  44804991
472   1994 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
9510  1994 Belgium   BE   Regulated  80647991
9610  1994 Belgium   BE Unregulated  44290197
503   1995 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
9810  1995 Belgium   BE   Regulated  80518704
9910  1995 Belgium   BE Unregulated  45564257
534   1996 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
10110 1996 Belgium   BE   Regulated  79513349
10210 1996 Belgium   BE Unregulated  50070276
565   1997 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
10410 1997 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77308936
10510 1997 Belgium   BE Unregulated  46737892
596   1998 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
10710 1998 Belgium   BE   Regulated  82610050
10810 1998 Belgium   BE Unregulated  47675059
627   1999 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
11010 1999 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77595053
11110 1999 Belgium   BE Unregulated  47150650
658   2000 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
11310 2000 Belgium   BE   Regulated  80435088
11410 2000 Belgium   BE Unregulated  46359701
689   2001 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
11610 2001 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77255899
11710 2001 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48873109
720   2002 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
11910 2002 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77914653
12010 2002 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48529972
751   2003 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
12210 2003 Belgium   BE   Regulated  78464806
12310 2003 Belgium   BE Unregulated  49488382
782   2004 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
12510 2004 Belgium   BE   Regulated  79430967
12610 2004 Belgium   BE Unregulated  49609916
2     2005 Belgium   BE         ETS  55363232
12810 2005 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77343444
12910 2005 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48294759
27    2006 Belgium   BE         ETS  54775328
13110 2006 Belgium   BE   Regulated  75869846
13210 2006 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48161044
52    2007 Belgium   BE         ETS  52795332
13410 2007 Belgium   BE   Regulated  73189198
13510 2007 Belgium   BE Unregulated  47422201
79    2008 Belgium   BE         ETS  55462028
13710 2008 Belgium   BE   Regulated  71854823
13810 2008 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48804185
108   2009 Belgium   BE         ETS  46206936
14010 2009 Belgium   BE   Regulated  61048912
14110 2009 Belgium   BE Unregulated  46593455
137   2010 Belgium   BE         ETS  50103980
14310 2010 Belgium   BE   Regulated  66648934
14410 2010 Belgium   BE Unregulated  46933097 
166   2011 Belgium   BE         ETS  46203056
14610 2011 Belgium   BE   Regulated  61319344
14710 2011 Belgium   BE Unregulated  42839297
195   2012 Belgium   BE         ETS  43006980
14910 2012 Belgium   BE   Regulated  58934979
15010 2012 Belgium   BE Unregulated  42459997
224   2013 Belgium   BE         ETS  45231176
15210 2013 Belgium   BE   Regulated  58383554
15310 2013 Belgium   BE Unregulated  43586891
255   2014 Belgium   BE         ETS  43853144
15510 2014 Belgium   BE   Regulated  56010346
15610 2014 Belgium   BE Unregulated  40380694
286   2015 Belgium   BE         ETS  44713916
15810 2015 Belgium   BE   Regulated  57375031
15910 2015 Belgium   BE Unregulated  42854461
317   2016 Belgium   BE         ETS  43655728
16110 2016 Belgium   BE   Regulated  56702848
16210 2016 Belgium   BE Unregulated  43540863
348   2017 Belgium   BE         ETS  43772976
```

`dput(head(Plot_df, 15))`delivers this

```
structure(list(year = c("1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", 
"1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", 
"1990", "1990"), country = c("Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", 
"Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus"
), iso2 = c("AT", "AT", "AT", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BG", "BG", "BG", 
"HR", "HR", "HR", "CY", "CY", "CY"), sector = c("ETS", "Regulated", 
"Unregulated", "ETS", "Regulated", "Unregulated", "ETS", "Regulated", 
"Unregulated", "ETS", "Regulated", "Unregulated", "ETS", "Regulated", 
"Unregulated"), emissions = c(0, 38264402.6689529, 24027827.7997971, 
0, 78614106.9221497, 41870291.5153503, 0, 69103153.6445618,         
9569791.66793823, 
0, 17530229.1374207, 5911735.70632935, 0, 3135556.17528036, 1507499.48878214
)), row.names = c("378", "2836", "3100", "813", "8310", "8410", 
"558", "16410", "16510", "438", "24510", "24610", "783", "3261", 
"3271"), class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I tried with the help of SO:

```
for(country in unique(Plot_df$country)) {

# Color settings: colorblind-friendly palette
c(
"#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
"#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7"
 ) -> cols

 ggplot() +
geom_line(
  data = Plot_df, # THIS IS WHAT YOU FORGOT
  aes(year, emissions, group = sector), 
  color = cols[1] 
) +
xlim(1990, 2016) + 
ylim(min(Plot_df$emissions), max(Plot_df$emissions)) + 
labs(
  x = "Year", y = "CO2 emissions", 
  title = sprintf("Emissions for %s", country)
) + 
theme(plot.margin = margin(.5, .5, .5, .5, "cm")) -> p 

 print(p) 

 ggsave(
plot = p, 
filename = sprintf("./%s.png", country), 
width = 6.5, 
height = 6
 )
}
```

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks in any case

Comment: It's great that you included an example dataset, but in this case you didn't give us multiple years per country and sector so we can't actually make an example plot.  However, one thing I noticed is that you are using continuous `xlim()` when your x axis variable is discrete.  I got errors because of this; maybe you want `xlim(unique(Plot_df$year))` or something?

Comment: @aosmith I have added the full data for two countries. Concerning the scale, I have set `Plot_df$year` to numeric, so this wasn't an issue. I got no errors. However, if I set it to `xlim(unique(Plot_df$year))` I get `Error in limits.numeric(c(...), "x") : length(lims) == 2 is not TRUE`

Comment: Make sure you include any changes like making things numeric in your example dataset! :)  The problem appears to be your y limits.  You set them to be between -50 and 50 but `emissions` are all either 0 or much bigger than 50.  Try just making a single graph for one country (rather than all the graphs in the loop) and I think you'll see this more clearly.

Comment: @aosmith Thank you for pointing this out. I have fixed it, but having another problem now. I will edit the post

Comment: Your new code seems to be missing the subsetting code you used in earlier versions to pull out the data for each country. This means you are plotting every country in each loop iteration.